# Regular expression to get all words inside specific patterns (% %)

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

All I want is this:

The sentences will have some words within % % and I want to extract all of them.

For e.g.

"This is a %varA% and %varB% and that one is a %VarC%"

and when I run it through the Javascript exec I'd like to get %varA%, %varB%, and %varC% in an array.

What would the pattern be? I've tried a number of iterations and none of them gets me each word separately. VarA and VarB etc. will all be words with just a-Z and 0-9, no special characters.

Comment: Did you try at least a few things?

Comment: `/%(\w+)%/g` should work for you.

Comment: To get the array try this "This is a %varA% and %varB% and that one is a %VarC%".match(/%\w+/g)

Comment: @ThomasAyoub I did. Didn't quite get it. Was using the \w+ in the wrong places.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [String match](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) with `/%(\w+)%/g` regular expression

**Explanation for** `/%(\w+)%/g`

- `%` matches the character **%** literally
- **1st Capturing group** `(\w+)`

  - `\w+` **match any word character** [a-zA-Z0-9_]

    - Quantifier: `+` Between
      **one** and **unlimited** times, as many times as possible, giving back as
      needed `[greedy]`
- `%` matches the character **%** literally
- `g modifier:`
  **g**lobal. All matches (don't return on first match)

```js
var string = 'this is a %varA% and %varB% and %varC%';

var regExp = /%(\w+)%/g;

document.write(string.match(regExp));
```

Comment: Thank you for answering and not calling me dumb.

Comment: @Gerry There is no such thing as a dumb question .. only dumb answers!